# Is there a way for a message send as a class to be consumed per Interfaces, this class implements?

Tags: masstransit

Let's say I have a class C, which implements interfaces I1 and I2

```
namespace Contract
{
    public class C :I1,I2
    {
    }
    public interface I1 { }
    public interface I2 { }
}
```

So, somewhere in my producer I'll publish C:

```
...
var message c = new C();
await _busControl.Publish(c);
...
```

And in my consumer for I1 I'd like to have:

```
        cfg.Host("localhost", "/");

        cfg.ConfigureMessageTopology();

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("subs", endpoint =>
        {
            endpoint.Durable = false;
            endpoint.Handler<I1>(context =>
            {
               ...
            });
          };
```

And in my consumer for I2 I'd like to have:

```
         cfg.Host("localhost", "/");

        cfg.ConfigureMessageTopology();

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("subs", endpoint =>
        {
            endpoint.Durable = false;
            endpoint.Handler<I2>(context =>
            {
               ...
            });
          };
```

Is it possible to configure such a routing with existing code?
If not, is it a right approach?
What would be a suggested approach if I'd like to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works by default using RabbitMQ, and also Azure Service Bus.

It doesn't work with Amazon SQS or ActiveMQ.

MassTransit refers to it as *polymorphic message routing* and you can see how the topology is configured in [the documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/topology/rabbitmq.html#publish).

To clean up your example, this is all you'd need:

```
namespace Contract
{
    public class C :
        I1,I2
    {
    }
    public interface I1 { }
    public interface I2 { }
}
```

Then publish:

```
var message c = new C();
await _busControl.Publish(c);
```

First consumer:

```
class OneConsumer :
    IConsumer<I1>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<I1> context)
    {
    ...
    }
}

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("one", endpoint =>
{
    endpoint.Durable = false;
    endpoint.Consumer<OneConsumer>();
};
```

Second consumer:

```
class TwoConsumer :
    IConsumer<I2>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<I2> context)
    {
    ...
    }
}

cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("two", endpoint =>
{
    endpoint.Consumer<TwoConsumer>();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It works like this out of the box. You don't need to do anything to make it work.

The only case where you might get in trouble, if you create a message using a function, which returns an interface. As MassTransit will use the generic overload `Publish<T>`, it will only use the interface. In that case, you can just say:

```
object message = MyMessageFactory();
await bus.Publish(message);
```

and MassTransit will figure out the types.

But, in your scenario, again, it just works.

Comment: Tx for the tip, Alexey